# Should I be using Iterations in AesGcm?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric, aes-gcm

Having read that RijndaelManaged is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212102/how-to-upgrade-from-rijndaelmanaged-to-aes) and [AesGcm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesgcm?view=net-6.0) (introduced in .NET Core 3.1) is preferred over [AesManaged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-6.0), I'm trying to implement [AesGcm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesgcm?view=net-6.0) using this [tutorial](https://www.scottbrady91.com/c-sharp/aes-gcm-dotnet) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891115/852806).

Here's my code:

```
/// Perform AES Encryption, returning the result as a byte array.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bytesToEncrypt">string, file or data represented as byte array</param>
/// <param name="passwordBytes">A unique password for the encryption (must be 32 bytes?)</param>
/// <returns>The data encrypted</returns>
public byte[] EncryptData(byte[] bytesToEncrypt, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    // Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60889345/using-the-aesgcm-class/60891115#60891115

    // Get parameter sizes
    int nonceSize = AesGcm.NonceByteSizes.MaxSize;
    int tagSize = AesGcm.TagByteSizes.MaxSize;
    int cipherSize = bytesToEncrypt.Length;

    // We write everything into one big array for easier encoding
    int encryptedDataLength = 4 + nonceSize + 4 + tagSize + cipherSize;
    Span<byte> encryptedData = encryptedDataLength < 1024
                             ? stackalloc byte[encryptedDataLength]
                             : new byte[encryptedDataLength].AsSpan();

    // Copy parameters
    BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(encryptedData.Slice(0, 4), nonceSize);
    BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(encryptedData.Slice(4 + nonceSize, 4), tagSize);
    var nonce = encryptedData.Slice(4, nonceSize);
    var tag = encryptedData.Slice(4 + nonceSize + 4, tagSize);
    var cipherBytes = encryptedData.Slice(4 + nonceSize + 4 + tagSize, cipherSize);

    // Generate secure nonce
    RandomNumberGenerator.Fill(nonce);

    // Encrypt
    using (var aes = new AesGcm(passwordBytes))
    {
      aes.Encrypt(nonce, bytesToEncrypt.AsSpan(), cipherBytes, tag);
    }
    


    return encryptedData.ToArray();

}


/// <summary>
/// Takes in an AES encrypted byte array, decrypts it and returns the resulting unencrypted byte array.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="encryptedBytes">A string, file or object represented as a byte array that's previously been encrypted.</param>
/// <param name="passwordBytes">The password used to encrypt the data. </param>
/// <returns></returns>
public byte[] DecryptData(byte[] encryptedBytes, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    // Decode
    Span<byte> encryptedData = encryptedBytes.AsSpan();

    // Extract parameter sizes
    int nonceSize = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(encryptedData.Slice(0, 4));
    int tagSize = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(encryptedData.Slice(4 + nonceSize, 4));
    int cipherSize = encryptedData.Length - 4 - nonceSize - 4 - tagSize;

    // Extract parameters
    var nonce = encryptedData.Slice(4, nonceSize);
    var tag = encryptedData.Slice(4 + nonceSize + 4, tagSize);
    var cipherBytes = encryptedData.Slice(4 + nonceSize + 4 + tagSize, cipherSize);

    // Decrypt
    Span<byte> plainBytes = cipherSize < 1024
                          ? stackalloc byte[cipherSize]
                          : new byte[cipherSize];
    using (var aes = new AesGcm(passwordBytes))
    {
      aes.Decrypt(nonce, cipherBytes, tag, plainBytes);
    }
    

    // Convert plain bytes back into string
    return plainBytes.ToArray();
}
```

One thing I've noticed, is there there doesn't seem to be a place for iterations.

For example, in AesManaged, I've always iteratated through like the following, as the iterations make attacks more complicated. I've followed a similar pattern for [password hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950611/how-to-create-a-pbkdf2-sha256-password-hash-in-c-sharp-bouncy-castle):

```
// Set Symmetric encryption algorithm
// Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645527/aes-encryption-on-large-files
var AES = Aes.Create("AesManaged");
AES.KeySize = 256;
AES.BlockSize = 128;
AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659214/why-do-i-need-to-use-the-rfc2898derivebytes-class-in-net-instead-of-directly
//"What it does is repeatedly hash the user password along with the salt." High iteration counts.
var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 100000);
AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
...
```

I appreciate the `nonce` will have an impact, but everything I've done before has relied on multiple iterations, so it seems odd not to be doing this in `AesGcm`.

AesGcm doesn't seem to have a means of iterating. Should I be iterating a part somewhere? If I should be iterating, how should I do this please?

Comment: Two things. The first is that your second sample generates the IV from the password. **DO NOT DO THIS** -- the IV needs to be unique for *each* encryption, particularly if the key is re-used. In your AES-GCM you're doing this properly, by passing random bytes to `nonce`. Second, your AES-GCM sample assumes that `passwordBytes` is already the correct length, meaning there is no need to use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` to turn an arbitrary-length password into a key of the right size. You can of course apply `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` to `passwordBytes` if you wish

Comment: @canton7 - thanks for this helpful response and clearing up my understanding. If you wish to detail this as an answer, I would be happy to accept it as the 'right' answer (after the required time delay).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - have done. Wanted to help searchers as the docs are so poor, but I guess we don't want people copying potentially incorrect code!

Comment: FYI, the dotnetfiddle link at the bottom of the answer you linked to has a bit more of a complete implementation, and it does use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` with iterations - since your question was "there doesn't seem to be a place for iterations".

Comment: This is how I'm using it based on the same answer, but I put it into a static class: https://gist.github.com/Reikooters/74fccfc666b53c61ebf9a3a89df7a02d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first important point is the your second sample generates the IV from the password. **DO NOT DO THIS!** The IV needs to be unique for *each* encryption, particularly if the key is re-used. You're doing this properly in your AES-GCM sample, where you generate a random nonce which is sent at the start of the ciphertext.

One basic example: imagine you encrypt two messages which start with the same text, using the same shared key. If you use the same IV for both, the two ciphertexts will also be identical. You do not want this.

---

AES requires a key which is exactly the right length. `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is used to turn an arbitrary-length password into a key which has the correct number of bytes. In your second sample, `passwordBytes` may be any length.

In your AES-GCM sample, `passwordBytes` is passed directly to the `AesGcm` constructor. Therefore, `passwordBytes` must already be exactly the right length.

If you wish, you can use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` on `passwordBytes` before passing the resulting key to the `AesGcm` constructor. This would let you use a `passwordBytes` of any length.

Answer (score 6):

> Having read that `RijndaelManaged` is deprecated and `AesGcm` (introduced in .NET Core 3.1) is preferred over `AesManaged`, I'm trying to implement `AesGcm` using this tutorial and this answer.

`RijndaelManaged` is deprecated but it is an implementation class. You should have been using [`Aes.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes.create?view=net-6.0) instead for a long time, preferring the no-argument constructor. Generally this will give you the optimized C/C++ version that can utilize the AES_NI instruction set that is - very likely - part of your CPU. The "Managed" classes are implemented using .NET and are comparably **dog slow**.

`AesGcm` can and should be used directly it seems, and adds authenticity and integrity to the cipher.

> ```
> using var aes = new AesGcm(passwordBytes);
> ```

Yes, no, that's not right. A password is not a key, and AES operates on keys, not passwords. So the part where the key (and possibly IV) are derived from the password is missing. This should be copied from the previous example that you mentioned. However, you *should* use `int nonceSize  = AesGcm.NonceByteSizes.MaxSize` as GCM works best for a 96 bit / 12 byte nonce (which is, I suppose what that gives you, in principle GCM doesn't have a functional *maximum* size for the nonce).

Of course, if performance permits, you can up the number of iterations. Calculating the nonce is fine, **as long as you change the salt** for each new ciphertext **as it should**. Beware that your scheme will horribly fail if the salt and nonce **do** repeat, so use a 128 bit / 16 byte salt just to be sure.

---

> AesGcm doesn't seem to have a means of iterating. Should I be iterating a part somewhere? If I should be iterating, how should I do this please?

That's correct, but that's because it *assumes* a fully randomized key. If you have a password, you will have to perform PBKDF2 (which the badly named `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class implements) or another *password based key derivation function*.

---

Beware that AES-GCM has an upper limit of 64 GiB (minus a few bytes).

Worse, it requires you to store all the plaintext / ciphertext in a buffer. It may not be the best option for file based encryption in that sense. You can encrypt chunks with GCM as well, but then you need to e.g. perform a HMAC over the authentication tags to make sure that the separately authenticated chunks are not reordered.

AES-CBC + HMAC over IV and ciphertext could be another option.

Answer (score 0):

AES GCM 256 Runs in framework 5 and above...
So, first write the program with framework 5 and above
I have written a sample class to use it and the library
using System.Security.Cryptography;
I have added to this class

```
 internal class class_Encrypt_Decrypt_AES_GCM
{

    public byte[] Encrypt(String key, string payload, byte[] header_aad, byte[] tag)
    {
        byte[] cipherText = new byte[payload.Length];
        try
        {
            //string key = "a05e19dc2682a72a8a9fe3d70707393e";Example
            // string payload = "Hello";Example
            //  byte[] tag = new byte[16];Example
            // byte[] header_aad = { 0x5a, 0xa5, 0x0, 0x6, 0x1a };Example
            int payload_len = payload.Length;

            byte[] bytes_key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);

            byte[] bytes_IV = new byte[16];
            byte[] send_IV = new byte[12];
            bytes_IV = IV_generator();
            byte[] bytes_payload = new byte[payload.Length];
            byte[] bytes_payload1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload);
            Array.Copy(bytes_payload1, bytes_payload, bytes_payload1.Length);
            Array.Copy(bytes_IV, send_IV, bytes_IV.Length - 4);

           
            int num = payload.Length;
            header_aad[3] = (byte)(num & 0xff);
            //----------hi byte
            header_aad[2] = (byte)(num >> 8 & 0xff);
            //==========================================
            AesGcm aesGcm = new AesGcm(bytes_key);
            aesGcm.Encrypt(send_IV, bytes_payload, cipherText, tag, header_aad);

            // String IV_STR = Convert.ToString(send_IV);
            // String key_STR = Convert.ToString(bytes_key);
            // String RES = Convert.ToString(cipherText);
            //example for Decoder
            //  aesGcm.Decrypt(send_IV, cipherText, tag, bytes_payload, header_aad);
            //  string result = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes_payload);


        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {

            int b = 0;
        }
        return cipherText;


    }

    private byte[] IV_generator()
    {
        byte[] byte_IV = new byte[16];
        Random rnt = new Random(DateTime.Now.Day);
        byte[] byte_time_rnd = new byte[16];
        rnt.NextBytes(byte_time_rnd);

        byte[] byet_sha384_date;
        SHA384 shaM = new SHA384Managed();
        byet_sha384_date = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Date.ToString()));


        for (int i = 0; i < byte_time_rnd.Length; i++)
        {
            byte_IV[i] = (byte)(byet_sha384_date[i] ^ byte_time_rnd[i]);
        }
        return byte_IV;

    }
```

In this class, there is also a function for making IV, in which I have used time parameters